# target div class outside parent div

Tags: jquery, class, target

how can i specify the `a` to target to the class `contenido_calendario` in jquery?

```
<div class="col1 sub_section_title">
    <article>
        <h3 class="article_header calendari">2012</h3>
    </article>
    <a href="#" class="button arrow_back_but" rel="tooltip" title="Click Aquí"></a>           
</div>
```

this is my code:

```
$("a").click( function() {    
    $(".contenido_calendario").hide();
    $(this).children(".contenido_calendario").toggle();
});
```

but it doesn´t work

Comment: There is nothing in your anchor tag....or just an accidental omission?

Comment: where is `.contenido_calendario` located?  I don't see it in your html

Comment: Your html does not have an element with the class `contenido_calendario`.

Comment: A `class` potentially refers to multiple elements, to which of the (potentially) multiple elements should this link *link*?

Comment: well what do you mean? i´m just trying to point to the "a" button

Comment: it´s the next div outside "col1 sub_section_title" div, sorry i put it in the question :S

Answer (score 1):

If there is in fact something in your anchor tag, you might want to try:

```
$(this).find(".contenido_calendario").toggle();
```

since `.children()` only targets *direct descendants* - and I'm guessing the `.contenido_calendario` is *not* a direct descendant of the clicked anchor.

EDIT (based on your comment "it´s the next div outside 'col1 sub_section_title' div, sorry i put it in the question"):

```
$(this).closest(".sub_section_title").next().toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget the preventDefault
without it you are refreshing your page

```
$("a").click( function(event) { 
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link has no children. therefore:

```
$(this).children(".contenido_calendario").toggle();
```

wouldn't find anything. because $(this) is referring to your link element.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information added to your post, I'd suggest (though untested):

```
$('a').click(
    function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').next().toggle();
    });
```